# Why does my C-program stop running?

Tags: c, switch-statement

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int lumens;
    int watts;

    printf("please enter Watts\n");
    scanf("%d",watts);

    switch (watts) {
        case 15:
            lumens=125;
            printf("%d\n", lumens);
            break;
        case 25:
            lumens=215;
            printf("%d\n", lumens);
            break;
        case 40:
            lumens=500;
            printf("%d\n", lumens);
            break;
        case 60:
            lumens=880;
            printf("%d\n", lumens);
            break;
        case 75:
            lumens=1000;
            printf("%d\n", lumens);
            break;
        case 100:
            lumens=1675;
            printf("%d\n", lumens);
            break;
        default:
            lumens=(-1);
            printf("%d\n", lumens);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

to me it seems like it doesn't run the switch-statement? But I don't get it

Comment: Read [our help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Comment: Please don't link us to code. Also note `scanf("%d",watts);`.. Think what's wrong here.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Most people aren't going to go off site to try to figure out your code.

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing it out. Will keep in mind when I ask my next question :)

Comment: @Kay: Better leave that `f`-suffix off, for higher precision, in case it matters. Also, that formula does not seem to be right.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem: your code could be much shorter. The first obvious thing you could do is to put the `printf("%d\n", lumens);` statement right before the `return 0;` statement and remove all other `printf("%d\n", lumens);` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf` should be

```
printf("please enter Watts\n");
scanf("%d",&watts);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `&` in `scanf` like

```
      scanf("%d",&watts);
```

Answer (score 0):

indicate memory location where to store value: `&watts` indicate memory location to store value.

```
scanf("%d",&watts);
```